TAR_BAD_ARCHIVE and Deprecated Warnings When Creating a Next.js App
I'm trying to create a new Next.js app using the following command:
npx create-next-app@latest my-next-app
However, I keep encountering errors and warnings like these:
npm WARN deprecated inflight@1.0.6: This module is not supported, and leaks memory.
npm WARN tar TAR_BAD_ARCHIVE: Unrecognized archive format
npm WARN deprecated rimraf@3.0.2: Rimraf versions prior to v4 are no longer supported.
npm WARN deprecated glob@7.2.3: Glob versions prior to v9 are no longer supported.
npm WARN deprecated eslint@8.57.1: This version is no longer supported.
npm ERR! code TAR_BAD_ARCHIVE
npm ERR! TAR_BAD_ARCHIVE: Unrecognized archive format
npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR! C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\<timestamp>-debug-0.log

I have tried clearing npm cache using npm cache clean --force, also reinstalled the latest LTS version of Node.js and verified node and npm versions, but the problem remains.
